# SQLite Query Trouble with WHERE Clause

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hi I am very beginner for android and in my app I am using SQLite for storing details they are below

1. name
2. productCode
3. mobileNo
4. email

Here my problem is WHERE Clause I mean I want to filter records using both name and productCode for this I wrote below code but I am getting exceptions please help me some one

MainActivity:

```
userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = userDbHelper.searchDetails(name,productCode, sqLiteDatabase);
```

userDbHelper:

```
public Cursor searchDetails(String user_name,String productName, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + UserContactDetails.NewUSerInfo.TABLE_NAME + " where" +UserContactDetails.NewUSerInfo.USER_NAME= '" +user_name + "' and UserContactDetails.NewUSerInfo.PRODUCT_CODE ='"+productName+ "'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

LogCat:
Process:

```
com.example.ram_ramadevi.sqllitetutorial, PID: 31620    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "fromuser_infowhere": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * fromuser_infowhere type = ramand name =8008824731
```

Comment: please show log ..

Comment: give space after `from` in your query.. like this `"select * from " + UserContactDetai....`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed a space there while concatenating the query string

```
 public Cursor searchDetails(String user_name,String productName, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + UserContactDetails.NewUSerInfo.TABLE_NAME + " where type = '" +user_name + "' and name = '"+productName+"'", null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: Process: com.example.ram_ramadevi.sqllitetutorial, PID: 5390 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: type (code 1): , while compiling: select * from user_info where type = 'ram' and name ='8008824731

Comment: select * fromuser_infowhere type = ramand name =8008824731 this query will definitely thow error instead use  select * from user_info where type = ram and name ='8008824731'  @Krish

Comment: " where" should be  " where " @Krish  add a space after where

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public Cursor searchDetails(String user_name,String productName, SQLiteDatabase db) {

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + UserContactDetails.NewUSerInfo.TABLE_NAME + " where type = '" +user_name + "' and name ='"+productName+ "'", null);
     return cursor;
  }
```

Comment: Process: com.example.ram_ramadevi.sqllitetutorial, PID: 5390
                                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: type (code 1): , while compiling: select * from user_info where type = 'ram' and name ='8008824731'

Comment: @Krish this is not the same exception and show me user_info table with columns and their data types.